# Wcf service fails silently from silverlight call, no exceptions

Tags: silverlight-4.0, enterprise-library, mvvm-light

I created a WCF service for logging using the enterprise library logging block. The service is working properly from an ASP.net website. Also the method is taking lists and primitive types as parameters so there should be no cross platform issues. So I place a reference of this service from visual studio into my silverlight project, which is mvvm by the way, and I make a call to the service. And nothing happens. No exception no logging nothing. At first I thought it was just an exception that was not propagating back to my service, so I placed a message immediately after my method's async call and that message ran fine. So I'm stumped. I also have a try catch block wrapping my service call and the catch block is never being called meaning an exception is not thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my error I was getting an exception before the call and that was preventing my service from being hit.